# Debugging drag and drop in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have drag and drop working in my application.
However, I have been running into an issue which I am not able to figure out whats causing it...

Basically, I have two itemsControl's where I am enabling drag and drop between them.
When the user drags items, I create a drag adorner and then do a drop preview on the control.

In some cases, when the drag adorner moves from source to the next itemsControl (i.e the target itemsControl where the drop will happen)...The OnPreviewDragLeave() method on the drag source
is not being called!

So the drag adorner just gets stuck on top of the source itemsControl.
This happens only in some cases, the only thing I can think of is that some other element is setting e.Handled to true maybe? 
But how can I effectively debug this in an easy way as these events get fired continuosly and setting breakpoints is not really an option...

Any suggestions are appreciated,
thanks

Comment: If you're suspecting it's an event handling problem, use Snoop [link](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com) to track routing of events in application. That should give you a clue what's going on...

Comment: i suspect you are dropping to an item's children instead